# How to make first column of html table fixed in responsive design

Tags: php, html

I need html  table  first column fixed in responsive.I have select box in my php page. I have used ajax to display data from database in html table. in responsive design  after selecting value in select box first td value is not fixed and other td values not scrolling.I have used jquery script to make html table first  column        fixed.With out selecting value in select box it is working in responsive .

Comment: Don't move data from the database server to the API for later use. Write a query that returns the data you want in one step.

Comment: `mysql_error()` - You can't mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Those are two totally different API's and aren't compatible in any way.

Comment: Have your thought about writing a single query and use joins?

Comment: Also show the second query how u wanna use this `$username`?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

you could do this with a single query

```
select *
from  admin  
INNER JOIN table2 ON admin.username = table2.t2_col_username 
WHERE admin.batchname= ?
```

and you should avoid the use of php var  in SQL (you are at risk for sqlinjection  )
for this take a look at prepared statement and binding param